# pyueye set the pixel clock

Tags: python, ueye

I am trying to set the pixel clock using pyueye.
to get it I do:

```
from ctypes import *
from pyueye import ueye
PIXELCLOCK_CMD_GET=5
pc = c_int()
ueye.is_PixelClock(self._hcam, PIXELCLOCK_CMD_GET, byref(pc), sizeof(pc))
```

and it works
to set it I tried:

```
PIXELCLOCK_CMD_SET=6
pc = c_int(100)
ueye.is_PixelClock(self._hcam, PIXELCLOCK_CMD_SET, byref(pc), sizeof(pc))
```

but it returns 125 (wrong input type apparently)

I tried pointer(pc) instead of byref etc ... but I haven't found any solutions.

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not working on that project right now so I can't test it but did you try to declare it as a pointer?

```
PIXELCLOCK_CMD_SET=6
pc = (c_int * 1)(100)
ueye.is_PixelClock(self._hcam, PIXELCLOCK_CMD_SET, pc, sizeof(pc))
```